# Spring FTP Inbound channel Adapter Error

Tags: java, spring, ftp

I have the following code using inbound channel adapter with java config (app that gets file from serv.) and I'm getting an error creating Beans, see more details below.

```
package com.ftp.hg;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Ftphg2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Ftphg2Application.class)
        .web(false)
        .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("host");
        sf.setPort(20);
        sf.setUsername("user");
        sf.setPassword("pass");
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Could anybody give me a clue of what's is wrong? PLEASE HELP
Error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2016-10-05 20:24:23.652[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m472[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftphg2Application': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpMessageSource' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application.main(Ftphg2Application.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpMessageSource' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:335) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.createMessageSource(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:61) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:130) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' defined in com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000.ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application.ftpMessageSource(Ftphg2Application.java:59) [classes/:na]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000.CGLIB$ftpMessageSource$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1c2c48.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000.ftpMessageSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'ftphg2Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator.<init>(DefaultFileNameGenerator.java:45) ~[spring-integration-file-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.<init>(RemoteFileTemplate.java:81) ~[spring-integration-file-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.<init>(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:113) ~[spring-integration-file-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer.<init>(FtpInboundFileSynchronizer.java:43) ~[spring-integration-ftp-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application.ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(Ftphg2Application.java:48) [classes/:na]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000.CGLIB$ftpInboundFileSynchronizer$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1c2c48.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ftp.hg.Ftphg2Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa602000.ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I have same issue...

Comment: I had many errors, starting with MAVEn dependencies, still with the issue?

Comment: I downloaded some sources and compiler told me similar thing - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER, so it looks like some dependency problem. I have to move to another issue, so I have no progress with this.

Comment: Yes, the initial problem was versions in the dependencies.